# Does git support wildcards in paths?

Tags: git, msysgit

I have looked, searched, and read documentation and can't really find anything about this.

Basically, I want to be able to do this:

```
git reset -- *.exe
```

or

```
git reset -- */some_executable.exe
```

Instead of this:

```
git reset -- some/very/long/path/some_executable.exe
```

Also it'd be nice to be able to do this:

```
git reset -- topleveldirectory/another/subdirectory/*
```

Instead of this:

```
git reset -- topleveldirectory/another/subdirectory/SomeFile.cpp
git reset -- topleveldirectory/another/subdirectory/SomFile.h
```

I *think* I can use the wildcard `*` in git-add to add files, but haven't found anything that works in the case above.

Any suggestions or pointers to where I can look for more info?

Using: git version 1.7.3.1.msysgit.0 on 64-bit Windows 7

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Git does support some pathspec globbing, but you need to be careful to shell-escape the characters so they aren't interpreted by in your case, msys bash, which doesn't support more sophisticated wildcard expansion.

EDIT: Also, for your reset example, you can just pass the directory as an argument to git reset and git will operate recursively.

```
git reset my/long/path
```

rather than

```
git reset my/long/path/*
```

Comment: Hey, that doesn't work att all!
I have a lot java files and running 

   git log --all -- '\*.java'

produces nothing.


find . -name '\*.java'

outputs tons.

Comment: Thats on git 1.7.4.4 on linux.

Comment: That version must have been broken. A build of 1.7.9.3 works as described. Beats me.

Comment: If you want to pass all java files try: git reset -- \\*.java

Answer (score 18):

To reset all exe files recursively from within a git folder, you can do the following:

```
git reset -- \*.exe
```

Or if you would like to add all java files within a specific sub-folder you can do that too, like this:

```
git add ./some/sub/folder/path/**/*.java
```

where ** means all folders recursively from this point in the path

Answer (score 10):

In some cases however, one does need to use wildcards in a specific way to target a specific subset of files and not just all files, especially when working with `git rm`, or `git checkout` or `git reset`. You can achieve the same by simply escaping the wild card character.

```
git rm app/assets/javascript/templates/projects/\*.jst.ejs
```

Answer (score 4):

At least in the case of subfolders/subfiles, there is no need for a wildcard.

```
git add .
```

...adds the current directory (.) and everything under it. The same goes for...

```
git add files/
```

...which would add `./files`, `./files/foo.txt`, and `./files/foo/bar.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

```
git diff '*word*'
```

works for me in iTerm / zsh