# Commit unchanged folder

Tags: git, github

> > [Git adding "unchanged" files to the stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600639/git-adding-unchanged-files-to-the-stage)

Can I do this with and entire folder without having to manually add each single file?

I have a webhook who didn't properly trigger on a commit and I would like to re-commit the folder. I see the file in my repo on github and they are on my local machine, but missing on the FTP server for unknown reason.

They arent in my git .ignore since if I maka a change, github detect it and proposed to do a commit.

I will investigate later why they went missing, but for now my site is down. =( I am using a branch and I would like to know what command should I do to re-commit /js for example so it get push with a new SHA ID, get pickup by the webhook and find its way on my FTP site. (thanks to DeployHQ!)

As it's my first question here and I am french, I hope I didn't broke any rule.

Comment: I think this page will help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012086/does-git-support-wildcards-in-paths

Comment: So I could 'technically' do: git update-index --no-assume-unchanged /js/ and that will reset the flag on all file in /js/. Do you know if such a query will be recursive for sub file? I will try it and keep you updated on the result... =)

Comment: err... result: ignoring path js/ - NO! that's the opposite! =) Consider it and let me upload the folder on a commit!!  Btw, thanks jiang for helping, or trying at least. =)

Comment: What happens if you do a `git status` in the root of your repo?

Comment: Show status as good! I have rename the folder js2/ then rename back to js1/ and the commit + the hook worked... So I am reviewing file by file the ftp and doing /2 /1 on the file I need to reset. =) I feel dumb because it's sure there is a way to say to git: Recommit my f* file please.